# Almost sure convergence of sum of countable number of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have a countable number of infinite sequences of random variables, $(X_n^i)_{i=1}^\infty$. I know that each sequence converges almost surely: for all $i \geq 1$,
$$
X_n^i \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}X^i.
$$
What do I need to assume in order to show that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_n^i \overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}\sum_{i=1}^\infty X^i?
$$

**EDIT: Below is the answer, built from the discussions below.**

(Much thanks to @Dominik for helping with this - he deserves the credit [and not blame if I still messed this up])

We must assume that there exists a function $g:\mathbb N_{>0} \to \mathbb R$ such that $\lvert X_n^i \rvert \leq g(i)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_{>0}$ and $i \in \mathbb N_{>0}$, where $\sum_{i=1}^\infty g(i) < \infty$.

**Proof**

By the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) (aka, Lebesgue's theorem), which requires our additional assumption, we have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty X_n^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n^i.
$$
This application of the dominated convergence theorem is described in more detail after the proof since I got it wrong on the first few tries.

So,
\begin{align}
\Pr\left ( \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty X_n^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty X^i  \right ) =& \Pr\left ( \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty X^i  \right )\\
\geq& \Pr\left ( \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \left ( \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n^i = X^i \right ) \right )\\
=&1-\Pr\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \left ( \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n^i \neq X^i \right ) \right )\\
\overset{\text{(a)}}{=}& 1-0\\
=& 1,
\end{align}
where **(a)** is because the countable union of an infinite number of measure zero sets is zero.

**Application of dominated convergence theorem**

Here I describe the application of the dominated convergence theorem in more detail. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) page says:

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real-valued measurable functions on a measure space $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$.

For us $S=\mathbb N$, and $f_n(i)=X_n^i$ for all $i \in S$. $\Sigma$ is just our measurable set and $\mu$ will be the counting measure.

> Suppose that the sequence converges pointwise to a function $f$ and is dominated by some integrable function $g$ in the sense that $$ \lvert  f_n(x) \rvert \leq g(x) $$ for all numbers $n$ in the index set of the sequence and all points $x \in S$.

For us $f(i)=X^i$. We require that $f_n(i) \to f(i)$. In our case that means that $X_n^i \to X^i$, which was one of our initial assumptions.

The domination requirement is that there is a measurable $g:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ such that $\lvert X_n^i \rvert \leq g(i)$ for all $n$ and $i$. Here "measurable" is w.r.t. the counting measure, which means that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty g(i) < \infty$.

Notice that requiring $\lvert X_n^i \rvert \leq \beta$ for some finite constant $\beta$ is not enough, since $g(i) = \beta$ does not satisfy this requirement. The example given by @Dominik shows a case where $\lvert X_n^i \rvert$ is bounded, and yet the order of the limit and infinite sum cannot be swapped (since no measurable $g$ exists).

> Then [...] $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_S f_n\, d\mu = \int_s f\, d\mu$$

For us, this means that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty X_n^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty X^i,
$$
which is the result that we want.

Comment: Are you sure you typed that right? The line you're questioning implies that $X^i=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n^i$

Comment: I think it's right. It's saying that we must be able to reverse the order of the limit and the infinite sum in certain cases - those cases being when $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty X_n^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty X^i$. From @Dominik's comment the proof appears wrong. The question remains whether the desired result can be shown in a different way.

Comment: Your assumptions are still too weak [c.f. the second paragraph in my answer]. Note that the function $g$ needs to be integrable, i.e. you need to bound $|X_n^i|$ uniformly by a summable sequence. It is certainly not enough for the sequence $X_n^i$ to be bounded.

Comment: Is the problem that if $\lvert X_n^i \rvert \leq \beta$, I can't just set $g(x)=\beta$ because then $g(x)$ integrates to infinity, and is thus not integrable? So, I need to make $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lvert X_n^i \rvert \leq \beta$ for some $\beta$? Is that what you mean by "bounded uniformly by a summable sequence"?

Comment: You see the problem, but your new assumption is still not enough [again, take a look at my example!]. You need $|X_n^i| \le g(i)$ for all $n$ where $g$ satisfies $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty g(i) < \infty$.

Comment: Ah, I see! Bounding $|X_n^i|$ doesn't ensure that such a $g$ exists, as the example in your answer shows. I really need the full constraint on $g$. I'll update the answer. Tomorrow I'll clean it up for future visitors. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The first equation in your proof is wrong, as sums and limits in general don't commute in a nice way. For this to hold you essentially need to apply monotone convergence or Lebesgue's theorem to the counting measure [recall that an infinite sum is essentially (!) the same as an integral w.r.t. the counting measure].

Take for example the sequence $X_n^i = I\{n = i\}$. These random variables are uniformly bounded and converge to $0$, yet their sum is constant $1$ and does not converge to $0$.

The restriction $X^i = 0$ can always be made, by simply considering $X_n^i - X^i$ instead of $X_n^i$ [assuming that $\sum X^i$ converges a.s.]. This is no useful constraint.

Comment: My $X_n^i$ are not non-negative, so I'm not sure that the monotone convergence theorem will work. I tried to use the dominated convergence theorem (Lebesgue's theorem) in an edit, and it seems to give the result I want. Also, the $X_n^i$ are not monotonic---$X_n^i$ can be greater than $X_{n+1}^i$.